# Download and upload DriveItem from shared OneDrive Folder with MS Graph SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm currently trying to implement several tasks that involve listing, uploading and downloading files from a shared OneDrive folder. This folder is accesible via the logged in users OneDrive (visible in his root folder). The listing part works pretty well so far, using this code:

```
string remoteDriveId = string.Empty;
private GraphServiceClient graphClient { get; set; }
// Get the root of the owners OneDrive
DriveItem ownerRoot = await this.graphClient.Drive.Root.Request().Expand("thumbnails,children($expand=thumbnails)").GetAsync();
// Select the shared folders general information
DriveItem sharedFolder = ownerRoot.Children.Where(c => c.Name == "sharedFolder").FirstOrDefault();

// Check if it is a remote folder
if(sharedFolder.Remote != null)
{
    remoteDriveId = item.RemoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId;

    // Get complete Information of the shared folder
    sharedFolder = await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[sharedFolder.RemoteItem.Id].Request().Expand("thumbnails,children").GetAsync();
}
```

So obviously I need to retrieve the shared folders information from the OneDrive that shared it with the other OneDrive. 
Next part for me is to list the contents of this shared folder, which also works pretty well like this:

```
foreach (DriveItem child in sharedFolder.Children)
{
    DriveItem childItem = await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[child.Id].Request().Expand("thumbnails,children").GetAsync();

    if(childItem.Folder == null)
    {
         string path = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid();
         // Download child item to path
    }
}
```

My problem starts with the "Download child item to path" part. There I want to download everything, that is not a folder to a temporary file. The problem is that OneDrive always answers my request with an error message, that the file was not found. What I tried so far is:

```
using (var stream = await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[childItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
using (var outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```

In another variant I tried to use the ID of the childItem ParentReference (but I think this will only lead me to the remote OneDrives ID of sharedFolder):

```
using (var stream = await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[childItem.ParentReference.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync())
using (var outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
}
```

After Downloading the files I want to edit them and reupload them to a different path in the shared folder. That path is created by me (which allready works) like this:

```
DriveItem folderToCreate = new DriveItem { Name = "folderName", Folder = new Folder() };
await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[sharedFolder.Id].Children.Request().AddAsync(folderToCreate);
```

The upload then fails. I've tried it like this:

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[sharedFolder.Id].Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
}
```

And also like this (which works if it is not a shared folder and I therefore use `Drive` instead of `Drives`):

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\temp\testfile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    string folderPath = sharedFolder.ParentReference == null ? "" : sharedFolder.ParentReference.Path.Remove(0, 12) + "/" + Uri.EscapeUriString(sharedFolder.Name);
    var uploadPath = folderPath + "/" + uploadFileName;
    await graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Root.ItemWithPath(uploadPath).Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
}
```

I couldn't get the `AddAsync` method (like in the folder creation) to work because I don't know how to create a `DriveItem` from a `Stream`.

If somebody could point me in the right direction I would highly appreciate that! Thank you!

Comment: At a glance your code seems fine. One thing you could try though is to use the `@content.downloadUrl` that you get back on files (it might be in the `AdditionalData` dictionary). You'd have to make an `HttpWebRequest` (or similar) to get the response stream, but it'll actually save you a round trip because `/content` actually performs a redirect under the covers.

Comment: That really did work! But it does not seem like the right way to do it. I would prefer using the Graph API to do it. The problem is, that for uploading a file (which would be the next task at hand) there is no such shortcut. Anyways a big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The request:

```
graphClient.Drives[remoteDriveId].Items[childItem.ParentReference.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync()
```

corresponds to [Download the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint and is **only** valid if `childItem.ParentReference.Id` refers to a [`File` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/file?view=graph-rest-1.0), in another  cases it fails with expected exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound Message: You
>   cannot get content for a folder

So, to *download content from a folder* the solution would be to:

- enumerate items under folder: `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{folderItem-id}/children`
- per every item explicitly download its content if `driveItem` corresponds to a `File` facet: `GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{fileItem-id}/content`

**Example**

```
var sharedItem = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderItemId].Request().Expand(i => i.Children).GetAsync();
foreach (var item in sharedItem.Children)
{
    if (item.File != null)
    {
        var fileContent = await graphClient.Drives[item.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[item.Id].Content.Request()
                    .GetAsync();
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(item.Name, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
           fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);

    }
}
```

**Example 2**

The example demonstrates how to download file from a *source* folder and upload it into a *target* folder:

```
  var sourceDriveId = "--source drive id goes here--";
  var sourceItemFolderId = "--source folder id goes here--";
  var targetDriveId = "--target drive id goes here--";
  var targetItemFolderId = "--target folder id goes here--";

 var sourceFolder = await graphClient.Drives[sourceDriveId].Items[sourceItemFolderId].Request().Expand(i => i.Children).GetAsync();
 foreach (var item in sourceFolder.Children)
 {
    if (item.File != null)
    {
        //1. download a file as a stream
        var fileContent = await graphClient.Drives[item.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[item.Id].Content.Request()
            .GetAsync();
        //save it into file 
        //using (var fileStream = new FileStream(item.Name, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        //    fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);


        //2.Upload file into target folder
        await graphClient.Drives[targetDriveId]
             .Items[targetItemFolderId]
             .ItemWithPath(item.Name)
             .Content
             .Request()
             .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileContent);

    }
 }
```

---

Instead of downloading/uploading file content, i think what you are actually after is `DriveItem` [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [`move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) operations. Lets say there are files that needs to be *copied* from one (`source`) folder into another (`target`), then the following example demonstrates how to accomplish it:

```
  var sourceDriveId = "--source drive id goes here--";
  var sourceItemFolderId = "--source folder id goes here--";
  var targetDriveId = "--target drive id goes here--";
  var targetItemFolderId = "--target folder id goes here--";

  var sourceFolder = await graphClient.Drives[sourceDriveId].Items[sourceItemFolderId].Request().Expand(i => i.Children).GetAsync();
  foreach (var item in sourceFolder.Children)
  {
      if (item.File != null)
      {
          var parentReference = new ItemReference
          {
               DriveId = targetDriveId,
               Id = targetItemFolderId
          };
          await graphClient.Drives[sourceDriveId].Items[item.Id]
              .Copy(item.Name, parentReference)
              .Request()
              .PostAsync();
         }
      }
  }
```

Comment: I tried the download part but can't get it to work. The first line of code (`var sharedItem = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[folderItemId].Request().Expand(i => i.Children).GetAsync();`) doesn't return anything for me. Perhaps I'm getting wrong, what the IDs are you#re using. Could you use the variables from my code example. That would make it easier to understand. Thank you alot!

Comment: And while copy or move would be nice additions (especially copy) I do also need to upload files which are generated locally. I've implemented all of this allready for the owner of the onedrive but realized it doesn't work for users that use a shared folder

Comment: Oh jesus!!! Got the download part working thanks to your example. That is a combination of parentreference and item id I didn't try! This is awesome! Just the upload part ... I'll try some more combinations :-D

Comment: I accepted the answer, before the bounty expires as it allready answers at least 50% of my question. It would be absolutely awesome if you also had a solution for the upload as I didn't get it to work

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, the answer has been updated with example for uploading a file (example 2)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much!